# need help regarding $_POST in PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem with my piece of code, kindly let me know where exactly I went wrong. I am sending an email to my account and the error I get is ... that I get only half of the information.

To get a clear idea of what I am asking I am attaching the code below.

```
<?php

$first_name = $_POST["name_t"] ;
$last_name = $_POST["lname_t"] ;
$contact=$_POST["contact"] ;
$email = $_POST["email"] ;
$adults =$_POST["no_adults_t"] ;
$children = $_POST["no_children"] ;
$address = $_POST["address"] ;
$date = $_POST["date_t"] ;
$message = "First Name : ".$first_name."\n\nLast Name : ".$last_name."\n\nContact Number : ".$contact."\n\nAddress :".$address."\n\nE mail :".$email."\n\n  Number Of Adults : ".$adults."\n\nNumber Of children : ".$children."\n\nReservation Date : ".$date;

$headers = "From:" . $email;
@mail( "someone@someone.com", "some subject ",$message,$headers);

echo "<pre>".print_r($_REQUEST, 1)."</pre>";
print $first_name;
print $last_name;
print $contact;
print $email;
print $adults;
print $children;
print $address;
print $date;

print "<body style="."background-color:gray"."></body>
<h2 style="."color:maroon;".">Thank You.Your information has been submitted.Our Representative would be contacting you shortly</h2>
<h4 style="."color:blue"."><a href="."index.html".">Click Here To Go Back to Main Page.</a></h4>"
?>
```

Comment: Please post the error message!

Comment: Not sure what the error is. If you too aren't sure, remove the @ from the beginning of mail function and try again. If you are receiving HTML mail, replace \n with <br />

Comment: just one quick notice, i hope you see it 2 that the bottom print is not closed, that will throw an error too, and would be good if you would the error message

Comment: Have you tried adding `"\r\n"` instead of `"\n"`? Email servers may expect the former and would otherwise treat the data as one long line.

Comment: @ tobiask , blockhead : the error is that i get the value of only email and the contact ... values of other variables are nowhere in the mail.

@ jack : no havnt tried it yet ... would it help ? i have mentioned the error part also.wats the error i encounter.
@ sunish menon : thank yu sir for answering .. i hace put '@' for suppresing warning messages.came to know abt it through googling

Answer (score 0):

try sending using SMTP (http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link:- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp, 
Also first use this "var_dump($_POST);" and check whether you are getting all values or not. I think email function not work on localhost.

Comment: See w3fools.com for recommending/introducing w3schools.com (Can't downvote your answer, not have enough rep points..

Comment: thanks fr yur answer ... yu r right rohit it doesnt work on localhost.i have hosted the site :)